# what difference between used to & to be used to?

Tags: meaning

I would like to know what difference between the two following phrases:

1. I used to smoke when I was in United States.
2. I'm used to living alone.

Is it correct to say "I'm used to live alone when I was teenager" Does it the same meaning?

Comment: *I'm used to smoke ...* means *somebody uses you to smoke* (maybe you are a cigarette!). I think you mean ***I used** to smoke...*, and ***I used** to live alone...* respectively.

Comment: @Fantasier Yes you are right I correct it.

Comment: @Fantasier: That's one possible interpretation. But since most people *aren't* in fact cigarettes (apart from gay ***fags*** in the AmE vernacular), *"I'm used to smoke"* is much more likely to be used to mean *"I **have become habituated to** smoke"* (i.e. - smoke no longer bothers me, I've gotten used to it).

Answer (score 1):

> I used to smoke when I was in United States - you don't smoke now but when you were in the United States, you did. [OxfordDictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/use?q=used%20to#use__14) describes the phrase *used to* as *an action or situation that was done repeatedly or existed for a period in the past.*

On the other hand,

> I'm used to *living* alone - you are accustomed to live alone. The [FreeDictionary describes](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/used+to) it.

Note the difference between *I **am** used to* and *I **used** to*. The former refers to your accustomedness whereas the latter talks about the things in past for a particular period and is not applicable anymore.